# base page session time out

Tags: asp.net

I'd like to implement a function that checks to see if the session is expired. Is a base page the right place to put this into?
Also, can I put a page method in a base page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way, but it seems to me that wiring an event handler to the [`HttpApplication.PostAcquireRequestState` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.postacquirerequeststate.aspx) is a more logical place.  This also makes your code work even if you forget to derive from your custom base page.

Comment: Do I implement the event handler code in a class library and call it from the base page in response to the event you just mentioned? Can I also put a page method in the base page or would it be better placed in a master page

Comment: Do it in either your `Global.asax` or a custom `IHttpModule`

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. It is very advantageous to keep things DRY by using inheritance.

Comment: Can I also put a page method in the base page or would it be better placed in a master page

Comment: It depends. Is your page going to call the method? If so, it would probably be best on your custom base page - it gets annoying to call a custom method on a master page.

Comment: Yes, the page method will be called from the client: pass json - receive json back. How different is it to call a page method from a base page vs a page method?